Prevent podman containers from using AAAA results when there are no ipv6 routes
I am having a problem in which applications running in podman containers are attempting to use ipv6 addresses, despite the container having no ipv6 routes (other than the expected link-local addresses).
If I start a podman container (as root) like this:
podman run -it --rm docker.io/alpine

I end up with a network environment that looks like this:
/ # ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if1389: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:77:37:96:bd:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.88.0.27/16 brd 10.88.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e877:37ff:fe96:bda5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
/ # ip route
default via 10.88.0.1 dev eth0  metric 100
10.88.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 10.88.0.27
/ # ip -6 route
fe80::/64 dev eth0  metric 256
multicast ff00::/8 dev eth0  metric 256

There is an ipv6 link local address, as we expect, but there is otherwise no ipv6 configuration inside the container. Despite this, applications looking up hostnames are apparently receiving ipv6 results and then trying to use them:
/ # curl --trace-ascii /dev/stderr https://index.crates.io
== Info: Host index.crates.io:443 was resolved.
== Info: IPv6: 2600:9000:2511:2e00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:5400:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:e800:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:b600:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:c00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:7000:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:3200:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1, 2600:9000:2511:cc00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1
== Info: IPv4: (none)
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:2e00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:2e00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:5400:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:5400:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:e800:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:e800:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:b600:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:b600:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:c00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:c00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:7000:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:7000:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:3200:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:3200:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info:   Trying [2600:9000:2511:cc00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1]:443...
== Info: Immediate connect fail for 2600:9000:2511:cc00:1f:a9f5:69c0:93a1: Network unreachable
== Info: Failed to connect to index.crates.io port 443 after 2003 ms: Couldn't connect to server
== Info: Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to index.crates.io port 443 after 2003 ms: Couldn't connect to server

This fails, of course. This particular problem is prevent rust programs from building inside containers.
The host doesn't have an ipv6 address, either (and the ISP does not provide ipv6 service in any case).
Is there a way to solve this at the podman layer? I would like to avoid globally disabling ipv6 support on the host.
The container in this example is running on the default podman network, which in theory already has ipv6 disabled:
# sudo podman inspect podman | jq '[.[0].name, .[0].ipv6_enabled]'
[
  "podman",
  false
]


It seems that the problem is really that there's no A result in the resolution though.

It looks like when curl had the operating system resolve the index.crates.io DNS name, it got only IPv6 addresses in response. Note the line: Info: IPv4: (none).
If the root cause is that the application makes the hostname resolution request without specifying IPv4/IPv6 in particular (i.e. using getaddrinfo(3)) and gives up before getting to try any IPv4 addresses, you might provision the container with a modified /etc/gai.conf file specifying that IPv4 is the preferred network type. See the comments in a default /etc/gai.conf file for instructions on how to modify it for IPv4 preference; basically just comment one line and uncomment another version of it.
But if the root cause is that the hostname resolution returns only IPv6 addresses for index.crates.io as suggested by the curl debug output, changing the preference to IPv4 won't help if the DNS has no IPv4 addresses to give. Even completely disabling IPv6 would not change things.
index.crates.io appears to be hosted by cloudfront.net, which is a large Content Delivery Network that has a large number of servers around the world, and a DNS-based load balancing system that attempts to direct each client to the nearest available server that can service the request.
This might be something like a miscommunication between your ISP and cloudfront.net: if cloudfront.net's global load balancers "think" that all your ISP's customers should be IPv6-capable, they might choose to provide only IPv6 addresses in their responses to requests coming from that ISP.

@TomYan correctly identified the root cause, which had me looking closer at the resolver configuration inside the pods, which looks like this:
nameserver 192.168.130.11
nameserver 192.168.1.1

192.168.1.1 I expected (that's the primary nameserver for my home network), but what is 192.168.130.11?
At some point in the distant past, I was running OpenShift Local, previously "CRC", which created the following libvirt network:
# virsh net-dumpxml crc
<network>
  <name>crc</name>
  <uuid>49eee855-d342-46c3-9ed3-b8d1758814cd</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='crc' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:fd:be:d0'/>
  <ip family='ipv4' address='192.168.130.1' prefix='24'>
    <dhcp>
      <host mac='52:fd:fc:07:21:82' ip='192.168.130.11'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

The resolvctl configuration associated with that network is:
Link 524 (crc)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
       DNS Servers: 192.168.130.11
        DNS Domain: ~testing


So that's where the address is coming from. Since I'm no longer running CRC, the simple solution was:
virsh net-destroy crc
virsh net-undefine crc

And now:
# podman run -it --rm alpine
/# apk add curl
...
/ # curl https://index.crates.io
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...
</html>

